# Bind mounts for renaming

Tags: files, mount, filenames, bind-mount

Can I do a bind mount on file "b" from file "a" such that file b also adapts the name of file "a"?
Ex:
`ls / a foo/b`
`mount --bind a foo/b`
`ls / a foo/a`

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. The file's primary identity in Unix-style filesystems is its *inode number* within a particular filesystem.

The name comes from the directory entry, which is actually separate from the file itself. A single file can have one name/directory entry (the usual case), many names (hard links), or no name at all (a file that has been deleted but is still open; can be used as normal until it's closed, at which point the deletion will be completed).

Hard links for directories are often disallowed, because they can cause directory hierarchies to loop "to infinity", which causes problems with backups, filesystem searches and any other programs that need to walk the entire filesystem hierarchy.

As a result, the bind mount cannot "carry" the name of the mounted object from one location to another. The name comes from the directory entry pointing to the mount point, and cannot be changed by the contents of the mount point.